# Replace characters and keep only one of these characters

Tags: java, string, replace

Can someone help me here? I dont understand where's the problem...

I need check if a String have more than 1 char like 'a', if so i need replace all 'a' for a empty space, but i still want only one 'a'.

```
String text = "aaaasomethingsomethingaaaa";

for (char c: text.toCharArray()) {

    if (c == 'a') {
        count_A++;//8
        if (count_A > 1) {//yes
        //app crash at this point
            do {
                text.replace("a", "");
            } while (count_A != 1);
        }
    }
}
```

the application stops working when it enters the while loop. Any suggestion? Thank you very much!

Comment: `text = text.replace("a", "");`  Strings are immutable

Comment: Also why do you have a endless `do-while` loop?

Comment: Also, if you're looping `while (count_A != 1)`, then you need to decrement the count every time a character is deleted, or your loop never ends. You also cannot remove characters from something while iterating through it with a `for`, because once you delete la character you've changed the loop (e.g., if there are 20 characters in the string, and you delete one, then there are only 19 left but the iterator still thinks there are 20, and you run off the end. When iterating and deleting, you have to start from the end and work toward the beginning.

Comment: Also maybe use a boolean rather than an int where an `a` has been found

Comment: Which `a` do you want to retain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to replace every `a` in the string except for the last one then you may try the following regex option:

```
String text = "aaaasomethingsomethingaaaa";
text = text.replaceAll("a(?=.*a)", " ");

    somethingsomething   a
```

### Demo

**Edit:**

If you really want to *remove* every `a` except for the last one, then use this:

```
String text = "aaaasomethingsomethingaaaa";
text = text.replaceAll("a(?=.*a)", "");
```

Comment: looks good, however I think they meant an empty string, not an empty space though.

Comment: Thats works for me! Thank you all for the answers!! And the other  answers above were very helpful because I was not getting out of the loop! I will take into consideration the response of @Scary Wombat, because it will undoubtedly be of great use in the future! Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it like

```
String str = new String ("asomethingsomethingaaaa");
int firstIndex = str.indexOf("a");
firstIndex++;
String firstPart = str.substring(0,  firstIndex);
String secondPart = str.substring(firstIndex);
System.out.println(firstPart + secondPart.replace("a", ""));
```

Comment: This answer is as enlightening to me as the @tim answer  Thanks to all!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong here but I have a feeling your talking about runs of **any** single character within a string. If this is the case then you can just use a little method like this:

```
public String removeCharacterRuns(String inputString) {
    return inputString.replaceAll("([a-zA-Z])\\1{2,}", "$1");
}
```

To use this method:

```
String text = "aaaasomethingsomethingaaaa";
System.out.println(removeCharacterRuns(text));
```

The console output is:

```
asomethingsomethinga
```

Or perhaps even:

```
String text = "FFFFFFFourrrrrrrrrrrty TTTTTwwwwwwooo --> is the answer to: "
            + "The Meeeeeaniiiing of liiiiife, The UUUniveeeerse and "
            + "Evvvvverything.";
System.out.println(removeCharacterRuns(text));
```

The console output is........

```
Fourty Two --> is the answer to: The Meaning of life, The Universe and Everything.
```

The Regular Expression used within the provided **removeCharacterRuns()** method was actually borrowed from the answers provided within [this SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43605292/replacing-consecutive-repeated-characters-in-java/44276389#44276389).

**Regular Expression Explanation:**

[image]